# React router - How to change behavior of browser back button on form confirmation page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm assuming many people working with forms in React came across this - basically once my user has submitted his forms he's directed to a confirmation page, but currently if he clicks on the browser's back button it takes him back to the last page of the form which is obviously not good. Any suggestions on what to do in such a case? I assume my two options for when the user clicks the browser back button in this case are either to redirect to a home page or to disable the back button (if that's possible), I've been reading into react-router v6' capabilities for such a situation but couldn't find an answer as userHistory has been depricated.